# How to include biml file when it has more than one root node?

Tags: ssis, biml

I have a biml file and want to use the include directive to bring in biml from another file that can get reused in other places, but it keeps giving this error when I do Check for Errors with BIDSHelper:

```
 There are multiple root elements
```

I see examples online of people using the include directive but no mention on this problem. I can't find any valid element to wrap my biml in, it has to be this chunk.

ErrorHandling.biml:

```
<UnionAll Name="Union Errors">
<InputPaths>
    <InputPath OutputPathName="Lookup Site.Error" />
    <InputPath OutputPathName="Detail Level Source.Error" />
    <InputPath OutputPathName="Site to Integer.Error" />
</InputPaths>
</UnionAll>
<DerivedColumns Name="Error Metadata">
    <InputPath OutputPathName="Union Errors.Output" />
    <Columns>
        <Column Name="execution_guid" DataType="AnsiString" Length="50" CodePage="1252">(DT_STR,50,1252)@[User::ExecutionGUID]</Column>
        <Column Name="error_time" DataType="DateTime" >GETDATE()</Column>
        <Column Name="PackageID" DataType="AnsiString" Length="38" CodePage="1252">(DT_STR,38,1252)@[System::PackageID]</Column>
        <Column Name="DataflowID" DataType="AnsiString" Length="38" CodePage="1252">(DT_STR,38,1252)@[System::TaskID]</Column>
        <Column Name="Step_Name" DataType="AnsiString" Length="50" CodePage="1252">(DT_STR,50,1252)"QI Load"</Column>
        <Column Name="Task_Name" DataType="AnsiString" Length="50" CodePage="1252">(DT_STR,50,1252)"Detail Level Check"</Column>
    </Columns>
</DerivedColumns>
```

Master.biml snippet:

```
 <RowCount Name="Row Count" VariableName="User.CheckRowCount">
        <InputPath OutputPathName="Lookup Site.Match" />
    </RowCount>
    <#@ include file="ErrorHandling.biml" #>
 </Transformations>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to get this to work- either change the extension of the file to something like .txt or simply don't select it when you "compile" your files with BIDSHelper and do "Check BIML for Errors" or "Generate SSIS packages".  Just select the main files that use any included files and contain proper XML.

Comment: Renaming to a `.txt` is a bad idea.  Not selecting it is the correct approach as the included files will be referenced by those selected to compile.